# Submit IOS App to App Store rejected because of iPad crash / SwiftUI

Tags: swift, iphone, ipad, swiftui, app-store

Im trying to submit an app to the App Store that I originally planned on only supporting with the Iphone. However, I found out that Apple requires apps to be run on iPad as well. I have clicked iPad in the general deployment info but is it possible for the iPad app to be just a mini version of what is seen on the iPhone. When I run the current code on an iPad simulator, it fills up the full screen and treats it like any other device. I don't want it to do that and just have an iPhone 1x/2x zoom size frame which I've seen other iPhone primary apps do. Is this possible in SwiftUI? Thanks for all your help.

I've also unchecked requires full screen on the App Store.

Comment: In prior versions of iOS it wasn’t required to support an iPad. But the iPad user could download iPhone only apps and they would display in the iPhone format. With SwiftUI it’s quite simple to support a layout that would work well on both devices. But that typically means you want to be more reliant on SwiftUI’s ability to infer the layout and auto resolve them.

Comment: I would recommend posting the crash you’re seeing on iPad so that we can help you debug that

Comment: @Jake, your first comment concerns me. *"In prior versions of iOS...."* I'm mostly a UIKit developer but have dabbled in SwiftUI. Could you provide a bit more detail? Any UIKit iPhone app has *always* had a "mini version" of it on an iPad. It improved with Auto Layout. Also, it's always been possible to create an iPad only app. (And all this includes split screen and/or multi-tasking activity for the iPad.) Is this somehow different when using SwiftUI? That wasn't my experience two years ago. What version of iOS (or iPadOS) was it not **required*?

Comment: After looking, you're right to be concerned. I've been doing a lot in the xcode betas and one of the project types through me for a loop. you can make a mac+ios app type and in the earlier version of the beta there was no option for iPad. It seemed that it was assumed you would design for both.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not check iPad in general deployment and your app should run as an iPhone app with the x1/x1 zoom option.